# Checking if the values of a Singly Linked List form a Palindrome

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to solve the [*following problem*](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/):

> **Palindrome Linked List**
>
> Given the `head of` a *singly linked list*, return `true` if it is a
> palindrome.
>
> *Input:* `head = [1,2,2,1]`
>
> *Output:* `true`

I'm getting a wrong result for the following test case:

```
[1,1,2,1]
```

Expected output is `false`, but my code returns `true` ([*screenshot*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tHFt.png))

*My code:*

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseRecursive(ListNode head)
    {
        if (head == null || head.next == null)
        {
            return head;
        }
       ListNode newHead = reverseRecursive(head.next);
       head.next.next = head;
       head.next = null;

       return newHead;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        ListNode head1=reverseRecursive(head);
        
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode curr1 = head1;
        while (curr != null && curr1 != null)
        {
            if(curr.val == curr1.val)
            {
                curr = curr.next;
                curr1 = curr1.next;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have used recursion to reverse the array and then compare the nodes of the *linked list* one by one, traversing through the list.

Class `ListNode` defined as follows:

```
public static class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    
    ListNode() {
    }
    
    ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information to answer the question. We need to be able to compile and run your code. Where is the code for `ListNode`?

Comment: Your way of reversing the list modifies the original `ListNode`s, you must not do that, you need to create new `ListNode` instances. Try printing the lists for `curr` and `curr1` and / or use a debugger to investigate what they actually have as their lists.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for pointing me that...i was totally incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The logic inside `isPalindrome()` is correct. The issue resides in the `reverseRecursive()` method.

Firstly, you don't have to reverse the existing list. Secondly, this method actually doesn't reverse the list, the list gets truncated in such a way that it contains only two first nodes.

You don't need to alter the *Linked List*. Instead, you can generate a **new** *Linked List*, in which each node is a copy of the node from the initial list (i.e. it has the same value) and nodes are linked in reverse order. Then inside `isPalindrome()` we can assign the head of the newly created reversed list to the variable `curr1`.

Note that according to the [*constraints of this task*](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/) it's guaranteed that there would be at least one node, hence `head` would never be `null`.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    ListNode revListHead = createReversedList(head);
    
    ListNode curr = head;
    ListNode curr1 = revListHead;
    
    while (curr != null && curr1 != null) {
        if (curr.val == curr1.val) {
            curr = curr.next;
            curr1 = curr1.next;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public ListNode createReversedList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode prev;
    ListNode currCopy = new ListNode(head.val);
    ListNode curr = head;

    while (curr.next != null) {
        prev = currCopy;
        curr = curr.next;
        currCopy = new ListNode(curr.val, prev);
    }
    return currCopy;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode cur = head;
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 1};
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        cur.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(head));
    
    cur = head;
    arr = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 1};
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        cur.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(head));
}
```

*Output:*

```
true    // [1, 2, 2, 1]
false   // [1, 1, 2, 1]
```

We can also approach this problem by dumping the *values* of all the nodes in a Linked List into an `ArrayList`.

And then iterate over its indices until the **middle** of the list (which is sufficient), checking the corresponding values at the front and at the back of the list.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    List<Integer> values = getListOfValues(head);
    int size = values.size();
    
    boolean isPalindrome = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        if (!values.get(i).equals(values.get(size - 1 - i))) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPalindrome;
}

public List<Integer> getListOfValues(ListNode head) {
    ListNode curr = head;
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while (curr != null) {
        values.add(curr.val);
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working for inputs like [1,2,2,1]. Output is false but it must be true.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Fixed. The order of operations in the `createReversedList()` was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question using this algorithm that gives me the best time complexity that I can think of.

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode reverse(ListNode head)
    {
        ListNode prev=null;
        ListNode curr=head;
        
        while(curr != null)
        {
            ListNode next=curr.next;
            curr.next=prev;//Assigning
            
            //Updation
            
            prev=curr;
            curr=next;
        }
//         head.next=null;
//         head =prev;
        
        return prev;
        
    }
    
    public ListNode findMiddle(ListNode head)
    {
        ListNode hare=head;
        ListNode turtle=head;
        
        while(hare.next !=null && hare.next.next !=null)
        {
             hare=hare.next.next;//Increment by two
            turtle=turtle.next;//Increment by one 
        }
        return turtle;//This will be at middle by then
    }
    
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        if(head==null || head.next==null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        ListNode middle= findMiddle(head);//1st half  end
        ListNode secondHalfStart=reverse(middle.next);
        
        ListNode firstHalfStart=head;
        while(secondHalfStart != null)
        {
            if(firstHalfStart.val==secondHalfStart.val)
            {
                firstHalfStart=firstHalfStart.next;
                secondHalfStart=secondHalfStart.next;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

In this, I have found the middle of the linked list using the hear and turtle approach(Floyd’s Algorithm).
I have reversed the second half of the list and compared the elements one by one.